# simple animation - extrusion dissapearing

Tags: extrude

I am quite new to Blender, my first project is a simple animation of a logo comprising the letters 'MNS' that get extruded and move about. The letter 'N' gets extruded and follows a path. However, during the motion, the extrusion *unintentionally* disappears but reappears towards the end of the path again. There are no keyframes in the timeline when this happens. The letter 'M' does the same, except that the extrusion does NOT disappear. As far as I can see all settings for object 'n.001' and object 'm.001' are identical. I don't understand why the two objects behave differently.
The .blend file can be found [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgZGGaNc8oBnxAV7688oJ9ThqCba?e=KQtyDT). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The extrusion is not disappearing. The letter N is moving downwards so the extrusion gets hidden by the ground plane.

Comment: Hey Mike, i tried to open your blendfile but the Video is not playable. Did you pack your file before uploading?

Comment: @EvripidisLalissidis The video is not necessary. Just go into the editor and see the animation there. But as I said, it's not disappearing, just going down.

Comment: Im not sure what exactly the desired result would be... Does Mike want the Z-Axis movement to stay constant?

Comment: Many thanks Gordon - I knew it had to be something trivial, but as i said I am a beginner... Much appreciated!